Some objects in scene render without materials
I have a problem I have not come across before.  In my viewport all of my objects appear with their materials and textures, however when I test render the scene, some of the objects render without materials.




I have been searching through other posts and they all seem to indicate that things can be turned on and off globally but I've never seen this happen to only a few materials.  As far as I can tell the materials on these objects are no different to other materials with fairly simple PBR setup.
Any ideas?

If you want us to help with your material problem it would be a good start to show us how at least one of the problematic materials looks in the Shader Editor.

Hi @GordonBrinkmann,  Thanks and sorry for the delay, I have been away and only just got back to working on this project.  I have added a shot of the shader editor.  Please note I didn't create the structure, this is from a plugin for export to Flight Simulator.  The materials that are blank in the render (and game) appear to have the same structure as other materials that work.  I am not sure which node to expand to inspect closer, so please advise if there's something I should look for.

Is it possible there are viewport hidden objects rendering over the normally visible ones?

What is inside the gLTF settings group?

Added the glTFSettings node expanded.  Looks like it just manages the Occlusion (red) channel of the comp at export whereas the Rough and Metal channel go directly into the BSDF.
